# How to fetch variables.env variables in Angular and assign it to environment.ts or environment.prod.ts

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have build a docker which contains angular 4 application ,other services like superlogn,feedparser and database couchdb.

Presently in my root folder i have a varibales.env file where all the variables are declared and can be accessed in superlogin and feedparser services

But if we access the varaiables in angular application liks

dbusername=process.env.username

then the error we getting in angular production is process is undefined?

unable to access process.env in angular 4 application?

the Github link for the project is

https://github.com/janastu/iihs_couch_services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Angular don't have access (and should not) to environment variables. This is very dangerous for your system.

If you want to expose your environments variables, which I don't recommend, you should create a Node application and make endpoints that return your environment variables.

Comment: i did not understood angular dont have access to environment variables,        how to pass variables to environments.ts from .env file

Comment: Only node can use `process.env`

Comment: how to access .env files in angular?

Comment: **You don't** !

Comment: what is you dont we cannot access it?

Comment: You **must not** access it. It's **forbidden** and **dangerous**.